# Not able to read back the audio binary data from realm db to play with AVPlayer

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.ios, realm

Due to some reason I am bound to store a recorded audio in Realm Db as Byte array kindly refer code below .

```
var byteArray = NSData.FromUrl(audioFilePath).ToArray();
```

I save this byteArray to db .

when I try to play the same audio after fetching it from db I am facing problem that mediaFile always remains null .

```
var nsdata = NSData.FromArray(byteArray); 

var mstring = NSString.FromData(nsdata,NSStringEncoding.ASCIIStringEncoding); //tried all encoding options from enum available )
mediaFile = NSUrl.FromString(mstring); // mediaFile always remains null
this.player = new AVPlayer(mediaFile);
this.player.Play();
```

Any help in above regard would be appreciated .

Comment: have you checked that each step of this process is returning the data that you expect it to?

Comment: Yes Jason ,everything is fine , I stored byte[] to db , fetched byte[] converted to nsdata .
if I use 
NSUrl.FromFileName(mstring); 

I am getting like this 
file:///Users/saket/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/749113E7-16ED-48E3-8653-047AAF1DAC8F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A08AF3DB-5D85-4315-8F9D-AE3C8A04799E/Wije.app/y%CC%88u%CC%80P%60%01%60

this is still not getting played

Comment: any audio file saved in realm and trying to read that back example could help

Comment: are you trying to save the path to the file, or the actual audio data itself?

Comment: did the AVPlayer work by using the origin string? I mean directly playing  without store and fetch.

Comment: Cole Xia yes It does . 

@jason - I am trying to save the data , audioFilePath is where the audio file gets stored at when recording is finished .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after reading the data back from db I was supposed to write it to a filelocation and an URL pointing to that location is what was needed to play back the mp3 .

fully completed code

```
                var nsdata = NSData.FromArray(byteArray);
            string fileName = string.Format("Myfile{0}.mp4", "saket");
            var urlPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

            Console.WriteLine(urlPath);
            var audioFilePath = NSUrl.FromFilename(urlPath);
            NSError err;
            nsdata.Save(audioFilePath, false, out err);

        //  var url = NSUrl.FromFilename(audioFilePath);

            this.player = new AVPlayer(audioFilePath);
            this.player.Play();
```

Comment: Would you recommend Realm for this use case (Storing audio files)?